# How to check if solution file (.sln) is up to date?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'd like to rebuild a project using MSBuild if any files contained in the project are out of date. I know I can do a clean build using:

```
MSBuild.exe MySoln.sln /t:Clean,Build
```

But I don't want to bother rebuilding if every file contained in the project is up to date. However, if any file is out of date, I would like to do a full clean build. Is there a command line solution for this?

Better yet, is there a way to check if a given solution is up to date without rebuilding anything (i.e. just return True/False)?

Comment: You could probably run something like msbuild  MySoln.sln /p:BuildSteps=BuildCompile and check if the output contains "All outputs are up-to-date." If not, not everything is up to date (but files will have been compiled already) and you can rebuild. Question is: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have several applications with overlapping dependencies and I'd like to automate rebuilding these applications if any input files have changed. I've had issues using incremental builds where msbuild would not rebuild everything necessary so currently I am doing a clean build of every application after any code change. I'd like to implement a quick check to see if a new change in code would even touch a given application so I can skip doing a clean build of it.

Comment: You might be better of figuring out why the incremental build doesn't work out, it should, and after all it's made to do exactly what you're after. Else my other comment still stands: the decision whether to build based on which files are/aren't up-to-date is made inside the `CL` task, and I have no idea how to extract just that logic from it, so I see no other way of figuring out if a build is needed than to actually call the CL task in the same way as msbuild does i.e. via BuildCompile